# Apache server file permissions

Tags: php, chmod, chown

I know this was brought up many times. Still I can not find a sutable answer.

I want to upload a file to a server and want to set temporary 777 permission to the file where I put content. I am the only owner of the file and the directory and it does not seem to be an option to change or add an owner from the control panel and I dont want to set 777 to that folder. Since neither apache nor script own the file chmod does not work. Is there a way to get the ownership to php, a particular script or the server throught chown function? The script that POST a file is not publically accessible btw.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if I am right or not.
First you can get the owner of the file with this

```
$filename = 'index.php';
print_r(posix_getpwuid(fileowner($filename)));
```

with

```
chmod('/var/www/folder/', 0777)
chmod('/var/www/folder/index.php', 0777)
```

you can change any folder or file to 0777
you can also check with chmod the file or folder have

```
if( chmod($path, 0777) ) {
    chmod($path, 0755);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer but i want to elaborate a bit before actually put the code there. I already know the owner, it is me, my login so to speak. I dont know how it could be helpfull if i get it from the script. Then i dont want to change chmod on the script itself, i want to chown a file so that the script could write there an uploaded content.

Comment: Just wanted to add. Chmod does not seem to work, cause i am the owner. Change from the control panel is not a problem. But script can not chmod the file, it does not own it in the first place.

Comment: The Script also needs the right 777 afaik, to change it.

Comment: I added chmod($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0777); to the script, but it did not help.